# compile openCV from source: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to compile openCV from sourc by following [these steps provided by the uses servo](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=166601)

However when I do so when I try to execute `sudo make` after having done:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON –D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON –D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_JPEG=ON -D .. WITH_JASPER=ON
```

I get the following error:

```
 *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Note that I need the provide the parameters written above when executing cmake in order for my software to work as expected.

I would like to know why I get this error and how I can solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but you should not use sudo so much... Only make install should need root permission.

Comment: there is a `..` at the end of the cmake command, which is required, but not in your copy-paste. That needs to be there or you will get something like `Could not find CMakeLists.txt` error and no makefile will be generated.

Comment: @JosephIreland sorry my bad when copy pasting. I did write it actually, will edit my post

Comment: can you give the output of the cmake command? if there is no makefile, then the error happens at this stage. You could be missing some library or some other error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you specified the correct OpenCV source directory? The usual approach is to create a *build* directory somewhere, `cd` into it and configure with CMake and then build there with `make`.

In the created build directory:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE *your configurations* /path/to/opencv/sources
```

And `make` in this directory (`make -j n` is also an option, where *n* is the maximum number of jobs to be run simultaneously, i.e use your available logical threads to speed up the process. You can go with 4 for example).

Additional tutorial: [build OpenCV on Raspberry Pi](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/)

Comment: I exactly followed that tutorial and tried it 4 times. Yes I execute those commands while being in the build directory.

Comment: @privetDruzia your command still not add up, the source directory should be at the end, without any -D switch.

Comment: @privetDruzia or make your life easier if you have your Pi with a display, use the CMake GUI. `sudo apt install cmake-gui`

Comment: What do you mean? What should the command look like, do you think?

Comment: @privetDruzia `sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON –D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON –D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_JPEG=ON -D WITH_JASPER=ON .. `

Comment: Why does this comment not have a bajillion upvotes? I've been scratching my head for 3 days because it seemed like cmake-gui was failing to generate a makefile.  Turns out, it's making my life easier, I just didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python2.7?

If you are then you need to change 
    INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON
to
    INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF

So I would rm -rf the build folder. Then rerun the cmake command (the way you had it before but with the change i mentioned above) and then after that make should work.